# IC50 and area under the curve

Tags: pharmacology

I was hoping to get some clarification on how drug response data (i.e. IC50) are presented. On publicly available datasets like Genomics of Drug Sensitivity in Cancer, area under the curve (AUC) values are also presented alongside IC50 values. How are these AUC values for a particular drug/cell line calculated and are they correlated with the IC50 values?  If I want to compare the potency and efficacy of many drugs for a cell line (i.e. rank the drugs from highest potentcy/efficacy to lowest) should I use the AUC or IC50 values?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you read this: [wikipedia: area under the curve (pharmacokinetics)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_under_the_curve_(pharmacokinetics))?

Comment: Area under the curve is the integral of the curve where plasma concentration is plotted against time. A xenobiotic can be potent but still have a large area under the curve, and vice versa. Toxicokinetic factors that affect the area under the curve is absorbance, distribution, elimination etc. Even a less potent xenobiotic can become a lot more potent if its half-life is increased (has a high AUC). If the xenobiotic is really potent (exerts its toxic effects at lower concentrations) it can become less damaging if its elimination rate from the blood plasma is high. Compare IC50 values.

Comment: Are you referring to area under dose-response curves? This is very different from pharmacokinetics. A comparison of AUC and IC50 in this context is given in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867413009604 . Basically, AUC takes effect size (% cells killed) into account, while IC50 does not reflect this.